# Redirecionamento de URLS

Tags: url, seo, redirecionamento

Bom dia!

Tenho 2 sites wordpress (1 vai ser apagado) e estão com posts duplicados, pôs exportei e importei no outro. Existe uma maneira de eu redirecionar todos as urls de uma vez? Exemplo:

Tudo que for www.site1.com vire www.site2.com, sendo assim se tivermos uma URL: www.site1.com/olamundo ela viraria www.site2.com/olamundo

Tem como fazer redirecionamento 301, de alguma forma? São mais de 500 posts, e precisaria redirecionar tudo de uma vez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Através do .htaccess você pode fazer o redirecionamento

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DOMINIOANTIGO\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NOVODOMINIO.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Jefferson, obrigado! Como ficaria se eu tivesse um dominio assim: www.meusite.com.br/blog e www.meusite2.com.br/blog ?

Comment: Acredito que RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.novodominio.com/$1 [R=301,L] deva resolver