# Redirecionamento de requisições com .htaccess

Tags: apache, url, seo, hospedagem

Necessito urgente de uma forma simples e prática de realizar o redirecionamento via .htaccess de preferência para um domínio alternativo de um site. 
Esta prática é para adotar medidas de SEO, já que há várias mídias já indexadas pelo Google e outros buscadores.

Exemplificando, tenho o site principal **oregionalsul.com.br** que está sendo movido para **oregionalsul.com**; o redirecionamento de forma simples eu já consegui fazer, o que acontece é que o carregamento das mídias é feito em um subdomínio e da mesma forma eu necessito encaminhar todas as requisições para o domínio `.com`.

O caminho relativo de uma mídia é o seguinte:

`https://midia.oregionalsul.com.br/2017/10/segunda_etapa_da_transferencia_de_carga_da_ponte_hercilio_luz_20171010_1160690858-1132x670.jpg`

ou seja, preciso que tudo que vem depois de `midia.oregionalsul.com.br` seja redirecionado para o mesmo endereço só que no domínio `.com`.

O conteúdo já está replicado em ambos os domínios, basta acrescentar ou retirar o `.com.br`.

#### Veja exemplo:

- **.COM.BR** = [https://midia.oregionalsul.com.br/2017/10/seg670.jpg](https://midia.oregionalsul.com.br/2017/10/segunda_etapa_da_transferencia_de_carga_da_ponte_hercilio_luz_20171010_1160690858-1132x670.jpg)
- **.COM** = [https://midia.oregionalsul.com/2017/10/seg670.jpg](https://midia.oregionalsul.com/2017/10/segunda_etapa_da_transferencia_de_carga_da_ponte_hercilio_luz_20171010_1160690858-1132x670.jpg)

---

Tentei com este tópico: [Redirecionamento de URLS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197201/redirecionamento-de-urls), sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui solucionar a questão há algum tempo, apenas para oferecer um feedback para a comunidade, segue conteúdo do `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^midia\.oregionalsul\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.midia\.oregionalsul\.com\.br$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/midia\.oregionalsul\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Utilizando um redirecionamento 301 é possível fazer isto. Se sua hospedagem é CPANEL, faça diretamente no painel.

- Crie um subdomínio
- Na listagem encontre o subdomínio criado e clique em **Manage Redirection**
- Preencha com o endereço para onde deseja redirecionar e salve.